# PHP File Generation - Mystery Line Feeds (0x0a) When Using MySQLi

Tags: php

I have a simple php script that looks like this, running on a RHEL 8 server with PHP 7.2.24:

```
<?php
// Establish Connection
include_once("db_connect.php");

// Perform any query
$sql = "SELECT now()";
// The following (mysqli_query call) should do nothing, yet echoes two line feeds
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo "TEST";
?>
```

If I retrieve this script output (e.g. with WGET) *directly into a file*, my file contents (hex dump) are:

`0a0a 5445 5354`

I did not echo these two line feeds that precede "TEST", and they are being inserted **only** if mysqli_query is executed.  (If I comment out that line, my file looks like `5445 5354` as expected)

Even stranger, if I do this on a different/remote server (CentOS 8 with PHP 7.2.24) from the very same client, it works as expected - mysqli_query does not add these line feeds.

What am I missing?  Is there some sort of control for this behavior, that is apparently set differently between my two systems?  Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the newlines don't come from `db_connect.php`? I would advise removing the closing `?>` from any scripts if you want to avoid unwanted characters in the output buffer

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

To clarify, the db_connect.php is just to establish the database.  I can do that without executing the query (with mysqli_query) and I do not get any line feeds.

I tried removing the closing ?> but it did not make a difference.  In summary, it's only if I include the line "mysqli_query" that the line feeds appear.

Comment: Then why did you accept the answer below parroting these comments?

Comment: Phil, you were entirely onto it.  I removed the ?> and it did not change anything, however ... but the leakage was totally coming from db_connect.php.  Thanks!

Comment: What you're describing where the linefeeds only show up if you execute `mysqli_query()` just doesn't seem possible. Without details of that script, this isn't really answerable (even though you got a solution that works)

Comment: Actually, the line feeds really were not present without ```mysqli_query()``` execution.  I don't understand why its inclusion triggered them to appear (from the bottom of db_connect.php) but that is the observed behavior.

Comment: "running on a RHEL 8 server with PHP 7.2.24" - please keep in mind that PHP 7.2 is out of support since years, and should no longer be used anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the extra line endings are actually from `db_connect.php`. Please make sure that you don't have any line endings after the closing `?>` tag in that file, or even better, remove the closing tag entirely.

Anything after a `?>` closing tag (including line breaks!) will be treated as output, and can leak into other files through `include`.

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much for your help!  I have been pulling my hair out all day on this one.  Sure enough, db_connect.php contained two line feeds at the very bottom!  That they only showed up if myqli_query was executed is what entirely stumped me.  Thank you!!!